# Cannot install jruby

Tags: asdf-vm

OS: macOS Catalina (`10.15.7`)

Shell: `zsh`

asdf: `v.0.8.0`

In my `.zshrc`:

```
export JDK_HOME=/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims
export JAVA_HOME=${JDK_HOME}
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}
. $(brew --prefix asdf)/asdf.sh
```

At a prompt:

```
work/proj(master)> which java
/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/java
work/proj(master)> which ruby
/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/ruby
work/proj(master)> which jruby
jruby not found
work/proj(master)> which gem
/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/gem
work/proj(master)> which bundle
/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/bundle
```

I realized I had `rbenv` and `asdf` configured when I tried installing gems in a `jruby` project today.  I decided to switch to `asdf`.  I believe I have removed `rbenv`, but it is possible there is something lingering that I missed.

I have also done a `brew uninstall ruby-build`.

In the `jruby` project, our `Gemfile` specifies:

`ruby "2.5.7", engine: "jruby", engine_version: "9.2.13.0"`

Trying to install `jruby` produces:

```
work/proj(master)> asdf install ruby jruby-9.2.13.0
Downloading jruby-bin-9.2.13.0.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/73a8c241a162e644c87e864c3485c55adedeb82a6fd80fa3cb538fdacda7af58
Installing jruby-9.2.13.0...

BUILD FAILED (Mac OS X 10.15.7 using ruby-build 20201005)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/w2/m3v3grd53s191ys4wjc1tcnr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201228141357.27332.TjSdh4
Results logged to /var/folders/w2/m3v3grd53s191ys4wjc1tcnr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201228141357.27332.log

Last 10 log lines:
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2020 17:11:23 GMT
ETag: "99df4eb89f88c7582bfe7c313daec7b4"
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 2cd732b3fedea7af49f60c3497dbaec3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ORD53-C3
X-Amz-Cf-Id: JksAVdI9wNtkTLb7k--bwYLHNrmbbhtI6FMFDQBm4h_OJi31nPbaLg==
Age: 10954

/var/folders/w2/m3v3grd53s191ys4wjc1tcnr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201228141357.27332.TjSdh4/jruby-9.2.13.0 /var/folders/w2/m3v3grd53s191ys4wjc1tcnr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201228141357.27332.TjSdh4 ~/code/work/proj
./ruby: line 446: /Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I suspect that error is coming from some sort of `rbenv` leftover, but I'm not sure what, since I have removed the `~/.rbenv` directory, and have done `brew uninstall rbenv` as well as cleanup `rbenv` from my `zshrc`.

The error specifies `/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims/bin/java`, implying an expected directory named `bin`, but my `shims` directory does not have any sub-directories.  I also suspect this is leftover from how `rbenv` did things.

How can I get `asdf` to install `jruby` ?

Update:

I worked around the issue by creating `bin` in `~/.asdf/shims/java` and symlinking `java` to `bin/java` so:

`ls -ltr ~/.asdf/shims/bin` ==> `java -> ../java`

Now, when I try to install, it get's past that and I am facing new errors:

```
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jruby-launcher' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you found a solution to your problem, I'll try to explain what was wrong when you asked the question.

Your original problem was with your `JDK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`:

```
export JDK_HOME=/Users/Ctreptow/.asdf/shims
export JAVA_HOME=${JDK_HOME}
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}
```

You do not use the ASDF java plugin to manage your `JAVA_HOME` and your `PATH` should already be set correctly by ASDF.

Your manual configuration results in jruby expecting a `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java` since the JAVA_HOME is expected to look like (with as example how Java would be installed on macOS):

```
❯ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7/Contents/Home
❯ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7/Contents/Home
bin     conf    include jmods   legal   lib     man     release
```

Which ASDF plugin are you using to manage the java versions? Is it the default https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java? (you can check this using `asdf plugin list --urls --refs`)

If you use that, you also need to include the JAVA_HOME script
`. $(brew --prefix asdf)/plugins/java/set-java-home.zsh` after the asdf script
`. $(brew --prefix asdf)/asdf.sh` in your `.zshrc`

If you use that you will have a correct JAVA_HOME, also after switching what version you want:

```
❯ asdf local java adoptopenjdk-8.0.275+1
❯ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/wessel/.asdf/installs/java/adoptopenjdk-8.0.275+1
❯ ls /Users/wessel/.asdf/installs/java/adoptopenjdk-8.0.275+1
ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION bin                lib                sample
LICENSE            include            man                src.zip
THIRD_PARTY_README jre                release
❯ asdf local java zulu-15.29.15
❯ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/wessel/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-15.29.15/zulu-15.jdk/Contents/Home
❯ ls /Users/wessel/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-15.29.15/zulu-15.jdk/Contents/Home
DISCLAIMER   bin          demo         jmods        lib          readme.txt
Welcome.html conf         include      legal        man          release
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by first installing a `java` version with:

`asdf install java adoptopenjdk-8.0.275+1`

and then ensuring it was set correctly for this project by doing:

`asdf local java adoptopenjdk-8.0.275+1`

After doing that, I was able to install the `jruby` version I needed with no issue.